# How would I access a specific value in an <li> element using the event target property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I want  to only access the c.symbol value that has been added to the li element created in the for loop within another function. How would I go about doing that?

```
for(let c of data){
        let node = document.createElement('li');
        node.textContent = c.companyName + ', ' + c.symbol; //only want c.symbol
        companyList.appendChild(node);
        node.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            if(e.target && e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "li"){
                populateCompanyInfo(e);
            }
        });
    }  
function populateCompanyInfo(e){
    //I want to be able to access the c.symbol value in here using the taget

}
```

Comment: Why not just call `populateCompanyInfo` with `c.symbol` as a parameter?

Comment: So you want to access `c.symbol` of the `textContent` of `event.target` in `populateCompanyInfo`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I believe `populateCompanyInfo` is an event handler.

Comment: It looks like the event handler is the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) attribute for storing data you want to attach to elements.

```js
let data = [{
  symbol: "EleFromStack",
  companyName: "Stack"
}];

let companyList = document.getElementById("companyList");
for (let c of data) {
  let node = document.createElement('li');
  node.textContent = c.companyName + ', ' + c.symbol; //only want c.symbol
  node.dataset.symbol = c.symbol; // Here I'm storing the c.symbol value
  companyList.appendChild(node);
  node.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "li") {
      populateCompanyInfo(e);
    }
  });
}

function populateCompanyInfo(e) {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.symbol)
}
```

```html
<ul id="companyList">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just `split` the `textContent` of `event.target` to get `c.symbol`:

```
function populateCompanyInfo(e) {
    var cSymbol = e.target.textContent.split(", ")[0];
    //Do something with cSymbol
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to keep the anonymous click handler function , copy `c.symbol` and pass it as an argument to `populateCompanyInfo`:

```
for(let c of data){
        let node = document.createElement('li');
        node.textContent = c.companyName + ', ' + c.symbol; //only want c.symbol
        companyList.appendChild(node);
        let cSymbol = c.symbol;
        node.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            populateCompanyInfo(e, cSymbol);
        });
    }  
function populateCompanyInfo(e, cSymbol){
    // c.symbol is the second argument.
}
```

You could also pass the entire data object  by calling `populateCompanyInfo` with `c` as its argument if you ever needed to access other data properties:

```
 populateCompanyInfo( c); // if the event object is not needed
```